# On Ubuntu 15.04 cannot use svn command with ssl v3

Tags: svn

After upgrade to ubuntu 15.04 I cannot any longer user svn command with a repository that requires SSLv3.

For example when I run svn update I see following error message:

```
Updating '.':

svn: E120171: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'xx/trunk'
svn: E120171: Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication

svn version: 
svn, version 1.8.10 (r1615264)
   compiled Jan  4 2015, 21:54:50 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

OpenSSL version:
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Just go into `~/.subversion` , and edit server, add the `ssl-client-cert-file` and `ssl-client-password`, maybe it will work.